# Can proof assistants reflect the informal notion of a “theory” as the formally logical notion of a “theory”?

Tags: coq, lean

Let us say that I wish to study and understand gauge symmetry using a formally verified mathematical programming language like Lean or Coq.

Lean has many libraries you can import to express mathematical concepts from a certain field of math, like set theory, logic, and others like topology and differential geometry and so on, I assume.

I am wondering if something like the “theory” of gauge symmetry could be seen as the same thing as the word “theory” in logic - the collection of all true statements resulting from some axioms.

So, in order to “study gauge symmetry”, it would actually be a matter of identifying what essential rudimentary logical statements are necessary to derive the important concepts and theorems in gauge symmetry (and those axioms being precise enough to exclude theorems from other fields.)

In other words, if we enumerated all sentences of some logic (say, first order logic), I assume all the theorems about gauge symmetry would be in there, but they would be too “hard to find”. Therefore, the actual task is adding certain axioms to first order logic, and only studying the theorems that come directly from enumerating all true statements coming directly from those axioms.

Is this possible? Is this a reasonable approach? What would come closest or be most similar?

---

For example:

> A gauge symmetry of a Lagrangian $L$ is defined as a differential operator on some vector bundle $E$ taking its values in the linear space of (variational or exact) symmetries of $L$.
>
> (Wikipedia)

Assuming we can define a Lagrangian system in the programming language (a pair $(Y, L)$, consisting of a smooth fiber bundle $Y \rightarrow X$ and a Lagrangian density $L$), and a gauge symmetry, would it be standard to try to constrain an automated theorem prover to only enumerate new theorems which make use of an initial statement (e.g., the definition of a gauge symmetry), combined with the formation rules of the logic? Does this count as a “fragment” of the logic, since we aimed to generate only a subset of the theory of the enclosing logic?

Comment: Any approach that involves enumerating all theorems or statements of a theory is unreasonable, unless you know how to beat exponential time complexity. Wikipedia states that a gauge symmetry is a certain Lean [structure](https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/struct.html).

Comment: @AndrejBauer  Hard is not the same as unreasonable: how can one beat the first incompleteness theorem rather?  IMO, this is indeed another question where we should rather explain that *true* (theoremhood) is not the same as *provable*...

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio: I will be delighted when you find a way to beat the combinatorial explosion that has hindered theorem proving for decades.

Comment: @AndrejBauer 1) the problem you mention is not really one of combinatorial explosion (what are you even talking about), rather one of how to automatically generate the *useful* theorems; but, more importantly and to the point, 2) that is *altogether irrelevant* and quire off mark relative to the present question and to similar questions: fundamental questions about what Logic or Theory even mean.

Comment: I am talking about the fact that there are exponentially many theorems up to a given size, so any attempt at exhaustively enumerating them is doomed. In all the decades of research, people have of course tried to cut down the number, precisely by thinking about useful theorems, and there is a lot that can be done, but the exponential growth is still there.

Comment: Regarding my comments being off the mark. The OP specifically plans to use enumeration methods (optimized in a way that nobody knows how to do despite a lot of research). Unless the OP is an expert in automated theorem proving, they're going to hit the exponential blowup immediately, so I think it's not off the mark to tell them that's a likely barrier.

Comment: Let me also explain why I use the word "unreasonable". First, the OP explicitly asks whether it's reasonable to approach theorem proving by (optimized) enumeration. The OP is not a specialist in the field (far from it), so they need a straight answer that will prevent them from wasting time. And I did not just say "unreasonable", but I qualified the comment by pointing to the combinatorial explosion problem. This is an obvious problem that everyone in the field knows about, but non-specialists may have some trouble appreciating the evil of exponential function.

Comment: In summary, I am happy that non-specialists come around and ask questions, but I think they deserve straight answers.

Comment: P.S. About 25 years ago I actually made [a serious attempt at enumerating all theorems of Peano arithmetic](https://math.andrej.com/2006/11/04/are-small-sentences-of-peano-arithmetic-decidable/) (looking for small undecidable statements), so I have first-hand experience with exponential explosion that I am speaking of.  So before anyone attempts to exhaustively enumerate gauge symmetry, perhaps they can try to get size 16 sentences of Peano arithmetic done. That's 3 symbols longer than what we did, so about 10 times harder. It's a good warm-up exercise.

Comment: P.P.S. The difference between size 13 and size 16 Peano arithmetic sentences is one of *quality*, not just quantity. At 16 symbols serious number theory starts to kick in, as one can write down non-trivial expressions *and* make non-trivial claims about them.

Comment: @AndrejBauer  We are answering two different questions: to me the OP is not even near to the problems you mention, where I find this particularly relevant: <<if we enumerated all sentences of some logic (say, first order logic), I assume all the theorems about gauge symmetry would be in there>>, which denotes that the OP does not even know the *fundamental* difference between *theoremhood* and *provability*: which is totally typical of beginners, the wondering as well as the mistake, and is the issue to really address.  To the point that I would rather say these questions are off-topic for PA.

Comment: I am hestitant to brand questions as off-topic, as some SE sites are quite hostile to beginners. But you're right, this particular question would probably be off-topic once we figured out what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.  If your question is about practical concerns, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  Can you define gauge symmetry in Lean or Coq?  Almost certainly yes!  It shouldn't be harder than any other similar area of mathematics.

Can you enumerate the theorems that mention your new concept `GaugeSymmetry`?  I guess, but you would get a bunch of junk like `GaugeSymmetry = GaugeSymmetry` and `∀ (x : GaugeSymmetry), 1=0 -> True`.  And even without stuff quite so silly, I would be surprised if you find a good solution to this combinatorial explosion.

But more importantly, I don't understand what you are looking to do here.  Why do you want this?

---

I think there is some confusion on the terminology of "theory", or of how Lean or Coq is typically used.

In its most general form, a "theory" in mathematics is when we have stumbled upon the right definitions.  In the theory of topology, we have the definitions of *topology*, *open*, *closed*, *compact*, *limit*, and so forth.  This "theory" forms the basis for a whole new understanding of other areas of mathematics.  It sounds like gauge symmetry already has that.  So you certainly should be able to write the definition of gauge symmetry in Lean and formalize theorems about it, but I don't think doing that is going to give you any brilliant new insights, except possibly as a way to systematize and record all the known knowledge in this field.

Another use case of the terminology "theory" is when one has a completely formal semantics of some mathematical notion.  A recent example of this is homotopy type theory, which is a formal language for working directly in something like the infinity groupoid formed by homotopy spaces (I'm probably messing this up).  This allows one to do synthetic homotopy theory, proving things about say the homotopy groups of the sphere without having to first go through topological spaces, etc.  But, working in a formal system like Lean or Coq doesn't automatically give you a synthetic version of your field.  Indeed, despite Lean's foundations being based on dependent type theory, just like homotopy theory, the proofs of Lean's homotopy theoretic results follow similar proofs to those found in the informal literature.

Finally, in logic, "theory" can sometimes mean a very particular thing, namely the set of all statements in some specific logical vocabulary, usually in first-order logic, which holds of a class of objects.  Sometimes these theories uniquely classify that family of mathematical objects, like the *theory of groups*.  Other times, they only get as close as you can get in first-order logic, like the first-order theory of the real numbers, which gives rise to the more general notion of a real-closed field.  But in both examples, there are lots of important properties that are not expressible in first-order logic, like *cyclic groups* or the *Archemidian property of the reals*.  Knowing which properties are first-order definable and which aren't is important since the former are preserved by logical gadgets like ultra-products.  Also, the first-order theory of the reals is a decidable theory with nice properties like quantifier elimination.

But a first-order theory is usually not the place to prove theorems.  You can't do modern group theory in the first-order theory of groups, nor can you do analysis in the first-order theory of the real numbers.  It just is not powerful or expressive enough.  You can't prove (or even state) Bolzano–Weierstrass in the theory of real-closed fields.  For that, you need to bring in all sorts of objects outside of first-order group theory like the integers, set theory, and the like.

You can, however, prove Bolzano–Weierstrass, and most all other theorems of mathematics, in ZFC (which is also a first-order theory) because ZFC is a more powerful and expressive theory, but without the nice properties of say the theory of real-closed fields.  Working in Lean (which is not a first-order logic) is more like working in ZFC.  It isn't used for its nice metatheory properties but for its expressiveness and practicality.  We don't make a distinction between the Lean or Coq statements that concern, say, groups and those that concern topological spaces.  Indeed, it is important that we can talk about both in the same theorem so that we can talk about topological groups for example.  Similarly, if you developed gauge symmetry in Lean or Coq, you would have access to all of Lean's or Coq's theorems and definitions for other related fields of mathematics.